# How to the the iv of the laravel session cookie

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to get the iv of the laravel session, but I can't find a way to do it.  I know it is base64 encoded json, so even if I could get the raw value of the cookie, I could get it from there.  Is there even a way to get this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming with 'iv' you mean ID...
Try:

```
\Session::getId();
```

https://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Session/Store.html

Comment: If you view the cookie in your browser it will be a string of hashed data, base64 decode that and there is a json array or data with mac, value and Iv (initialisation vector I think), it's this data that I want to access from within my app. Is this possible?